# Equivalent of get-msolsubscription via Microsoft's graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have an o365 tenant, for which I can check expiration of applied susbscriptions on the tenant via the result of an MSOL commandlet 'get-msolsubscription'. How can I do this using Microsoft's graph api? (Looking for rest api references)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs.
You can get subscription information (equivalent to the cmdlet above) using the subscribedSkus API:  https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_get

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for this response. In particular I'm looking for the expiry of the susbscription on the tenant. Get-MsolSubscription returns a property called 'NextLifecycleDate', but the rest api call does not give me this information.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not currently exposed by Graph.  Please file a UserVoice request for this feature: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: I have created a feature request [here](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/cfcee553-5396-ed11-a81b-000d3ae32cd0) to include NextLifecycleDate in the API. Please upvote the feature request (rather than this comment) if you need this data too.